# Which is the better way of declaring intent and start activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, start-activity

I have seen some `Intent` declarations on Youtube, Stack Overflow and elsewhere, and I have found two types of `Intent` declarations.

First type :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Second type :

```
startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
```

My question is which is the better way to declare `Intent`? Is there any significant difference between the two declarations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in performance, it depends on your preference actually.
Personally, I prefer the first option because assigning `Intent` to a new variable is clearer and I can easily add more extras later.

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly preference. Which is easier to read/understand? I always use the first.

If you ever need to add intent extras or set it's action, you'll want to go with the first anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It will work the same but if you want to set flag of activity launch or you want to put some values/objects in Intent for sending to target activity, the first way will be more  clear and easily understandable.
eg.

```
    // First type
    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("name","xyz");
    intent.putExtra("email","abc@gmail.com");
    startActivity(intent);

    // Second type
     startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class)
    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    .putExtra("name","xyz")
    .putExtra("email","abc@gmail.com"));
```